# ActionBar on the TOP and BOTTOM on Android App

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an Android app and I want to have 2 ActionBar (one on the top and another on the bottom) like this: http://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_pattern_considerations.png

I'm using [Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and for now I created only the top ActionBar. I serched in the web, but I didn't find a solution yet, only some piece of code.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

[How can I force the Action Bar to be at the bottom in ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics)

[Changing position of Android Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132066/changing-position-of-android-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private View contentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(contentView);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) contentView.getParent().getParent();
        View view = layout.getChildAt(0);
        layout.removeViewAt(0);
        layout.addView(view);
    }
```