# Using sherlockactionbar tabs for top and bottom

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm kinda new to SAB and currently i'm facing an issue to have 2 or 1 actionbar with tabs that separated to top and bottom.
I've managed to put my tabs at the bottom, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434942/actionbar-on-the-top-and-bottom-on-android-app) solution given by Gopal Rao:

top:
[image]
bottom:
[image]

My question is how to seperate the tabs so I can have this three at the bottom and another 2 at the top?

Comment: I think you should use a tab bar and a navigation drawer: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: @ErickFilho Thanks for the fast response but that's not exactly what i'm searching for since I've seen such a thing in another app so I guess it's possible.

Comment: What app? I'm curious!

Comment: https://lh5.ggpht.com/JJNopD1zhyKXxj8VqpnbpUDjZUBel2FC3G5EKaTKceozH6LOc_v535OPTujd1xMmw1Y=h900-rw